STM32L073 Retargeting printf() Issue
Below code, I aim to use printf() by UART protocol on STM32L073V8T microcontroller. PD5 pin is used for USART2_TX function to transmit data on UART. When I open serial monitor, I see no data.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32l0xx.h"


#define APB1_CLK        2097000
#define UART_Baudrate       115200

//Function prototypes

static uint16_t compute_uart_bd(uint32_t Periph_Clk, uint32_t BaudRate);
static void uart_set_baudrate(USART_TypeDef *USARTx, uint32_t Periph_Clk, uint32_t BaudRate);
void uart2_write(int ch);
int __io_putchar(int ch);

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t *pRCCEnableReg = (uint32_t*)0x4002102C;                // RCC GPIO Enable Register+
    uint32_t *pRCCAPB1EnReg = (uint32_t*)0x40021038;                // RCC APB1 Enable Register+
    
    uint32_t *pPortDModeReg = (uint32_t*)0x50000C00;                // Port D Mode Register+
    
    uint32_t *pPDAFRlwReg   = (uint32_t*)0x50000C20;                    // Port D Alternate Func Mode Register+
    
    uint32_t *pUSART2Cr1Reg = (uint32_t*)0x40004400;                // USART2 Control Register+

    
    //1. Enable RCC Clock
    *pRCCEnableReg |= (1U<<3); //Enable Clock For Port D+
        
    //2. Set Mode of Port D Pin5
    //Clear PD5
    *pPortDModeReg &= ~(1U<<10);
    *pPortDModeReg |= (1U<<11); //Set Alternate Function+
    
    //Set Alternate function type to UART2_TX (AF0)+
    *pPDAFRlwReg &=~(1U<<20);
    *pPDAFRlwReg &=~(1U<<21);
    *pPDAFRlwReg &=~(1U<<22);
    *pPDAFRlwReg &=~(1U<<23);

    *pRCCAPB1EnReg |= (1U<<17); //Enable Uart2 module+

    uart_set_baudrate(USART2, APB1_CLK, UART_Baudrate);

    *pUSART2Cr1Reg  = (1U<<3);  //Configure Transfer Direction - Transmitter Enable+
    
    *pUSART2Cr1Reg |= (1U<<0);  //Enable UART module

    while (1)
    {
        //uart2_write('2');
        printf("Hello\n");
        for(volatile int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
    }
}

void uart2_write(int ch)
{
    /*Make sure transmit data register is empty*/
    while(!(USART2->ISR & (1U<<7))){} 
    
    /*Write to the transmit data register*/
    ch = (ch<<1); //In order to avoid issue that I discovered previously
    USART2->TDR =   ~(ch & 0xFF);
}

static void uart_set_baudrate(USART_TypeDef *USARTx, uint32_t PeriphClk, uint32_t BaudRate)
{
    USARTx->BRR = compute_uart_bd(PeriphClk,BaudRate);
}

static uint16_t compute_uart_bd(uint32_t PeriphClk, uint32_t BaudRate)
{
    return ((PeriphClk + (BaudRate/2U))/BaudRate);
}
    
int __io_putchar(int ch)
{
    uart2_write(ch);
    return ch;
}

printf() does not work and I see nothing on serial monitor. Could you please help with my code ?
Thanks in advance.

Does your UART work if you use uart2_write directly? Did you run your program in a debugger? Are you maybe stuck in some loop? If you cannot use a debugger for some reason, use some IO Pin to toggle some LED and wath with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.

Initially, I tested uart2_write(int ch) function in while loop by calling it like ''uart2_write('Y') '' in order to send only 1 character on TX pin and it was working very well. I tested uart2_write function on serial monitor (using PuTTy). But when I add __io_putchar function, it does not work and printf is not working.

Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Can you check with a debugger that your function __io_putchar is actually called when you use printf? Please explain in your question the purpose of the bit-shifting and bitwise negation of ch in uart2_write.

Your register pointers should be volatile to ensure the compiler doesn't muck around with them (e.g. re-ordering them). Better yet, use CMSIS which will define all the registers and bits nicely for you. You probably need a delay between enabling a peripheral's clock and accessing its registers.

What library are you using?  Is __io_putchar() the correct retargetting function for your library? It is not the usual retargetting function for newlib or ARM's library.  You may also need to disable semi-hosting.

Magic numbers make programs impossible to debug.

*pPortDModeReg &= ~(1U<<10); it will not clear 2 bits for sure.
